# Подсчитать количество нулей и единиц в массиве

Tags: c#

Прошу помочь найти ошибку. Считает все элементы

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

            var k = richTextBox1.Lines.Count(s => s == "0" || s == "1");
            string[] b = richTextBox1.Lines;
            int n = b.Length;
            int[] a = new int[n];
            int i;

            for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
                a[i] = Convert.ToInt32(b[i]);                  
                if (a[i] == 0){
                {

                    textBox1.Text =Convert.ToString(k);

                }   }

                 if (a[i] == 1)
                {
                    {
                        textBox2.Text = Convert.ToString(k);

                    }
                }

            }

        }
```

Comment: Эм, а для чего цикл `for`?

Answer (score 1):

У тебя похоже ошибка в строчках:

```
textBox1.Text =Convert.ToString(k);
```

У тебя там , судя по коду, подсчитаны элемент, которые равны 0 и 1.

И ты каждый раз выводишь одно и тоже значение. Правильнее было завести какой-нибудь счетчик и инкреминитировать его при достижении условия.

Так же не ясен смысл цикла for, если ты через LINQ умеешь считать 0 и 1:

```
var k = richTextBox1.Lines.Count(s => s == "0" || s == "1");
```

Почему бы так же не сосчитать 0 и 1 отдельно?